# After integrate SWRevealViewController, appear all black on the screen

Tags: ios, storyboard, swrevealviewcontroller

As title, I had been integrate SWRevealViewController into the open source project as the link below

https://github.com/swiftcodex/Swift-Radio-Pro

and I had followed the step by step through the tutorial from appCoda

that teaches about SWRevealViewController

but it occur just black screen on simulator,

I had checked the step by step through tutorial and make sure i didn't miss anything,

and my source project download link as below:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27473655/Swift-Radio-Pro-master-test1.zip

I am wondering how to solve this problem or what did I miss

Thanks in advance for any reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into your code StationsViewController viewDidLoad was not been called up due to wrong implementation in storyboard.

Open storyboard->Select reveal view controller scene(which is a root view controller)->Now in both this segue make green color view controller as 
identifier = sw_rear & class = SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController. Also for another other segue identifier = sw_front & class = SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController.

And now definitely it will work as i am able to get the radio list as home screen after i compile your code.

Edit: 29 Aug
considering my above explanation i have added two screenshots of storyboard and inspector. Go through it and let me know still you have any queries.

[image]

[image]

Added two more images kindly have a look.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, is it possible to share your project to me,
I had check my project to change the setting that you said,
but it didn't works, I though I got some misunderstanding

Comment: Considering my above description i am adding 2 screenshots of storyboard with inspector, kindly have a look at it and let me know still if it is not clear to you.

Comment: I check the screenshot setting , It seem like same as my uploaded project,
pardon me, which part should i modify?

Comment: http://imgur.com/q3D8hcA 

http://imgur.com/tutUdqV

sorry, I had changed it, but still can't figure out it

Comment: Get the zip of working code from below link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycmmpjgyjg48odq/Swift-Radio-Pro-master-test_working.zip?dl=0
Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, its really helpful,
i m wondering what did you modify,
because i have change all the things same as you

Comment: You can start working further in my code.
Happy coding